# Have tmux windows inherit `activate`d anaconda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, environment, tmux, miniconda

For convenience and given that [`activate`-ing an environment is crazy slow](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8609), I want to activate an environment and then start a `tmux` session.

I want all new `tmux` windows to also have the environment activated.

I want different `tmux` sessions to be able to support different anaconda environments.

How do I go about this?

Are there any gotchas such that this isn't supported by `anaconda` / `miniconda`?

Comment: The `conda activate` or `source activate` commands simply set up a bunch of shell variables, mostly environment variables. If you can inherit the environment, you should also inherit the active conda environment. Maybe without the prompt (PS1).

Answer (score 5):

What I've done to address this problem is:

- In `.tmux.conf`, copy `CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV` environment variable to session environment

  ```
  set-option -ga update-environment 'CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV'
  ```
- In `.bashrc`, reactivate the conda environment if one was activated:

  ```
  if [ -n "$CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV" ]; then                                                                                                                                         
      __conda_reactivate                                                                                                                                                       
  fi
  ```

  Note 1: this assumes that `__conda_reactivate` is available because of `conda init` or similar.
  Note 2: in older versions of conda, it's `_conda_reactivate` (just one leading underscore).

This is faster than `conda activate <env>` and also different environments can be used before creating different tmux sessions.

Comment: Sadly `__conda_reactivate` costs me about 1.3s on a pretty grunty laptop... not something I'd want to wait for every time I start a open a new `tmux` window.

Answer (score 0):

The top answer is not ideal, and as [Tom Hale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5353461/tom-hale) mentioned, it's relatively slow - especially if you need several panes/windows.

Instead, use the CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV variable in a script that creates and organises new panes. Then use tmux send-keys to activate the original conda env in the new panes on creation.

Please see my answer here for details https://stackoverflow.com/a/66312869/8490364