# tmux create new pane or window with current activated conda environment

Tags: conda, tmux

When I create a new pane or window using tmux, I'd like to use the same conda environement I was just using.

I.e. I'm now using a conda env named `XXXenv`, and I use `Ctrl+b` + `%` to create a new pane, what I want is the new created pane is activated by the conda env `XXXenv`.

In fact, I have tried [Have tmux windows inherit `activate`d anaconda environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55913834/have-tmux-windows-inherit-activated-anaconda-environment), but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Have tmux windows inherit \`activate\`d anaconda environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55913834/have-tmux-windows-inherit-activated-anaconda-environment)

Comment: short answer: this isn't supported, but you can sort of work around it the way the other question suggests.

Comment: Did you ensure that you followed Note 1 in the proposed duplicate's accepted answer? I.e., your shell is configured to best practices by having run `conda init`?

Comment: In fact, I'm not quite understand what does Note1 mean. Would you mind give details about how to set?

Answer (score 1):

Heyo, there's an environment var called CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV. Create a bash script that defines pane layout, and use this var to send the original pane's active conda environment to any new panes. Then call it by some tmux shortcut.

*dev-sesh.sh*:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

current_session=$(tmux display-message -p '#S')
current_conda=$CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV

tmux split-window -v -p 75 -b
tmux select-pane -t 1
tmux split-window -h -p 50
tmux send-keys  -t "$current_session.0" "conda activate $current_conda" 'Enter';
tmux send-keys  -t "$current_session.1" "conda activate $current_conda" 'Enter';
tmux send-keys  -t "$current_session.2" "conda activate $current_conda" 'Enter';
tmux send-keys  -t "$current_session.0" "clear && figlet Welcome" 'Enter';
tmux send-keys  -t "$current_session.1" "clear" 'Enter';
tmux send-keys  -t "$current_session.2" "clear" 'Enter';
tmux rename-window "dev";
```

*tmux.conf*:

```sh
bind -n C-n send-keys 'bash ~/.dotfiles/dev-sesh.sh' Enter
```

*result*:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, this tmux plugin should give you the conda behaviour you are looking for.
https://github.com/oluevaera/tmux-conda-inherit

I've tested it and it works with bash and zsh, on both Linux and Mac OS.
I've only tried the 'micromamba' version but it should work with conda/miniconda and mamba too.