# Unable to activate conda environment with a spawned tmux window

Tags: python, conda, tmux

I have a workflow that spawns a new `tmux` window and executes a command inside that fresh window.

The command being executed is a Python application that requires a specific `conda` environment.

I have just realised that once that new window is invoked, it is invoked with the default `conda` environment. When I try to invoke the `tmux` window with a `conda activate myEnv` command, I am getting an error.

Here is the command I have used in my test:

```
tmux new-window -n:mywindow 'echo "__START__"; conda activate py37; echo "___END___"; sleep 5'
```

The following is the error I'm getting within the `tmux` window that is invoked:

```
__START__

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.


___END___
```

Any ideas?

Further details:

```
conda 4.7.12
Linux (Ubuntu 18.04)
Python3.7
tmux 3.0a
vim-dispatch (the plugin that invokes a new pane to run my app)
```

Answer (score 0):

conda stuff is all in the shell you are using, so whether it bash or something else, you need to make sure you've run *conda init*, and the CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV environment variable exists. I have a semi-related answer here that may help someone - https://stackoverflow.com/a/66312869/8490364

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly the same problem recently. In my case, I've run `conda init` already, outside `tmux`. But it didn't help solve the problem. Consequently, I didn't solve it directly, but found a workaround.

Basically, with conda activated is not a must to run the Python app that requires packages installed in that conda environment. Let's assume that when you run `conda activate py37 && which python3` outside `tmux`, it gives you `~/miniconda3/env/py37/bin/python3`. Then in `tmux`, you may just run the Python app with `~/miniconda3/env/py37/bin/python3` rather than bare `python3`. I know it's not perfect, but it works.